# Why does submit work with form_tag and not with form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form_tag form associated with a gem pg_search that works with a form_tag as below without ajax for the moment in pure html, yet when I try to make it work the same way with a form_for the submit does not pass.
Do you know why?
In passing do you know the equivalent in form_tag of the helper "url: search_path" which is commented in the form_for?
Thank you

```
1. Le form_tag

<%= form_tag new_product_association_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], id: "text_field", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Find a product" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary", id: "submit-search"%>
<% end %>


2. le form_for

<%= form_for product_associations_url, as: :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field params[:query], id: "text_field" %>
  <%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-primary", id: "submit-search" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: "do you know the equivalent in form_tag of the helper "url: search_path" which is commented in the form_for?" The signature is `form_tag(url_for_options = {}, options = {}, &block)`. So its the first ordinal parameter which can be a string or a hash passed to `url_for`. Its also very unclear what you are actually asking here - what is the exact problem you are facing and what are the steps to reproduce it?

Answer (score 1):

Rails provides several ways to create HTML for a form.

1. `form_tag`: This generates the  HTML in most raw form. You specify various attributes and resulting form is generated with no Rails magic.
2. `form_for`: This is Rails way of creating forms associated with a resource, e.g.: a product. You have to pass in the object which you want to create / update. So, the way you are writing `form_for` is incorrect. One more issue (typo) is instead of using `as` to specify method, you should use `method`.

Basic Usage of `form_for`:

In Controller:

`@product = Product.new`

In Views:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that the [`form_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) helper expects a record as its first argument, not an URL. I suggest switching to [`form_with`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) which also allows for URL usage.

Furthermore the [`text_field`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-text_field) usage also isn't valid. You should still provide the name (`:query`) of the input field.

```
<%= form_with url: product_associations_url, as: :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :query, value: params[:query], id: "text_field" %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Example usage can also be found all over the [Action View Form Helpers guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

Comment: If this answer doesn't solve your issue I'd like to take a look at the generated HTML for both the `form_tag` and `form_with` helper.